# Stably sort N elements in this restricted "cmov" language

Tags: sorting, atomic-code-golf

The following problem is taken from the real world — but indubitably `code-golf`!
In this puzzle, the programming language is fixed, and your job is to write the most efficient program in this fixed language. The language has no loops; a program is a straight-line sequence of instructions. Each instruction consists of exactly three characters — an opcode and two operands — and in fact there are only four possible opcodes:

- `<xy` — Compare the value in register *x* to the value in register *y*; set *flag* = L if *x* < *y*; *flag* = G if *x* > *y*; and *flag* = Z otherwise.
- `mxy` — Set the value in register *x* equal to the value in register *y*. (This is "move.")
- `lxy` — If *flag* = L, then set the value in register *x* equal to the value in register *y*; otherwise do nothing. (This is "conditional move," or "cmov".)
- `gxy` — If *flag* = G, then set the value in register *x* equal to the value in register *y*; otherwise do nothing. (This is "conditional move," or "cmov".)

For example, the program `mca <ba lcb` means "Set register *c* equal to the minimum of *a* and *b*."

The program `mty <zy lyz lzt` means "Stably sort the values in registers *y* and *z*." That is, it sets *y* to the minimum of *y* and *z* (breaking ties in favor of *y*) and sets *z* to the maximum of *y* and *z* (breaking ties in favor of *z*).

The following 16-instruction program stably sorts the values in registers *x, y, z*:

```
<zy mtz lzy lyt
max mby mcz
<yx lay lbx
<zx lcx lbz
mxa myb mzc
```

**Your task is to find the shortest program that stably sorts *four* registers *w, x, y, z*.**

A trivial Python implementation is available [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1xbqjPq9b) if you want to test your solution before (or after) posting it.

Comment: You'll receive imaginary bonus points if you find a second (shortest) program that stably sorts *five* registers.

Comment: This reminds me of Zachlike programming, specifically the programming in [Shenzhen I/O](https://store.steampowered.com/app/504210/SHENZHEN_IO/).

Comment: Can we assume that the flag is initialized to 'Z'?

Comment: What does "stable" sorting mean when values that compare as equal are actually equal?

Comment: What if you compare with a register that hasn't been set? or move from a register that has not been set?

Comment: @user1502040 Why do you need conditional move before testing?

Comment: @l4m2 I guess you don't, just picking up on am ambiguity.

Comment: @user1502040: "Can we assume that the flag is initialized to 'Z'?" No. The flag's initial value is undefined (i.e. using `l` or `g` before your first `<` instruction is simply verboten).

Comment: @Tbw: "What if you compare with a register that hasn't been set? or move from a register that has not been set?" Same answer as above: excluding the input registers, every register's initial value is undefined (i.e., reading the value of a non-input that you didn't previously set is simply verboten).

Comment: @Albert.Lang: "What does "stable" sorting mean when values that compare as equal are actually equal?" I'm not sure I understand your question. But see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/zo3bWhsGE) for a concrete example of how a "stable sort" is distinguishable from an "unstable sort": `mty <zy lyz lzt` is stable and `mtz muy <yz lty luz myt mzu` (which swaps _y_ and _z_ even when they're equivalent) is unstable.

Comment: I mean if  "equal" truly means "equal" and not just "equivalent" then you cannot tell whether equal elements have been swapped or not.

Comment: @Albert.Lang: Ah, I see. You're either making a deep but ultimately irrelevant point about [the identity of indiscernables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles), or nitpicking my use of the phrase "set x equal to y" in place of the more jargony "assign y to x". Feel free to read it as "assign" (and infer that such assignment faithfully copies even the [non-salient attributes](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2479.pdf) of the object, the ones that don't participate in equality) if that floats your boat higher.

Comment: My point is neither deep not philosophical. Your wording ("cmov", "register")  strongly suggests an assembly-like setting.The average reader will understand a register as carrying a simple value, a number, not something that would have "attributes that do not participate in equality".

Answer (score 6):

## 21 instr

```python
  '<wx', 'gtw', 'gwx', 'gxt',
  '<xy', 'guy', 'gyx', 'gxu',
  '<yz', 'gtz', 'gzy', 'gyt',
  '<wx',        'gxw', 'gwu',
  '<xy',        'gyx', 'gxt',
  '<wx',        'gxw', 'gwt'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRNc5swEL3zKzbpASmhSdz25Il7q2c605nk0BvDgZg1lgsSlUSM0@lvdxcJY4eS2uWiYXff27cfUrW1KyU/7t5d3NZG3z4JeYvyGSpnDgJRVkpbEBa1VaowQZDhErDBRW3xUatcpyWr/BmBsalFPg0AlkqDACGh87U2ALEEEd8lMJtBeB96G3hUTAZyQPgSdmYK9h4RT5Kkhd33hg/OMB1Ai7ehn09Acw/F4lhiOZDo2Cj6iGoEVfSoXobP4n3/xZX/gys/waXR1lrCd12jn9ozarHcdkN7kF9lVdvD7ET7G9FoK1xYzNwUHSER//p9PFKdyhxZgZI5DOdeo8@@WGmmdMZojhzewyEKrgl9DRPeKnWmWLQyqTCp7KmV2lczTwuDZ4ghVna@oItZXzeJ4vueD3L@1dAc7aMyRjwV6JppHpbfUOZ2xaTjqDrnlwJLlNa0i5Y@LQiar8T6R1FKVf3UxtbPm2b7EsZTmRyhPGXbrP3lu6GuZPXCsisWD7kTuALJ@Rg@FkfX8bWT2jQkuqG2aWs2gsoIw5u1EpIZegMwYwYtE5y@UZlxjNROYzUzdckmLuc6aw5DuqMlyxruXwHyuDVGzr26rImwjUVZl6hpcpQqeUu4E6CFtOxyPwG/UwZSjVO4jAYAfpjfa8fI1Tgsnzy8ZW1wq@PUzPuFPuu2dY19tbp9ZfNUFJiBkm05o4Az97TLOld6rmrtZTOXrQuNd0AP8qYJI3pW7MYd3V9jwyhovc3W/df@2HbeuvPS@jqsP166oD3WcXUfgboE9TFz790O8o5jbbgjbxIEqTF0O8YHOCg4gk989wc)

---

Neil suggests that reordering into this may get more clear:

```python
<wx gtw gwx gxt
<xy gty gyx gxt
<wx     gxw gwt
<yz gtz gzy gyt
<xy     gyx gxt
<wx     gxw gwt
```

This looks more like insertion sort

---

---

For large enough amount of element, a \$\tilde {\mathrm O} \left(n\right)\$ sorting algorithm exist. Here I construct a \$\mathrm O \left(n \log^2 n\right)\$ one using a \$\mathrm O \left(n \log n\right)\$ [sorting network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), which seems reducible: (say the input is `A[0..n-1]`

1. Set `O` to `min(A)` and `I` to `max(A)`.

Notice that if `O = I`, then all elements are equal, and no swap would apply.

2. Let `B[i][j] = i & (1 << j) ? I : O` for `0 <= j < log2(n)`.
3. Do sorting network on `A`, each element `A[i]` together with `B[i]`.

To do a multi-element compare:

```python
T = O
if (P[0] < Q[0]) T = I
if (P[1] > Q[1]) T = O
if (P[1] < Q[1]) T = I
if (P[2] > Q[2]) T = O
if (P[2] < Q[2]) T = I
...
if (P[9] > Q[9]) T = O
if (P[9] < Q[9]) T = I
if (T > O) swap
```

This makes a swap in \$\mathrm O \left( \log n\right)\$

Comment: This also reduces the three-register sort from 16 to 12 instructions.

Comment: Very nice! But more boringly symmetric than I'd expected. ;) I mean, it's literally bubble sort — bubble max(w,x,y,z) up to z, then bubble max(w,x,y) up to y, etc. Do you think it's generally the case that stable-sorting _n_ elements in this restricted language requires (_n_-1) + (_n_-2) + ... + 2 + 1 `<` instructions?

Comment: I note that if we were restricted to _swaps_, then bubblesort would be optimal: (1) a stable sort cannot safely swap two non-adjacent elements; (2) [each (adjacent) swap can undo only a single inversion](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/12/13/bubblesort-rocksort-shakersort/#finally-i-thought-it-was-interes); and (3) there can be as many as (_n_-1) + (_n_-2) + ... + 1 inversions. But our language permits not only swaps but also "rotates" (x gets y, y gets z, z gets old x) and even "copies." Maybe we can exploit that to do better somehow?

Comment: @Quuxplusone I can sort n elements in \$\text O(n \log^3 n)\$ by finding two different elements to record position, and it should be far from optimal

Comment: @l4m2: That sounds very neat; but I'm failing to see what you mean by "find two different elements to record position." Could you provide a (sample implementation, keywords to google, etc)? Also feel free to post as a second answer, if it's too long for a comment.

Comment: @Quuxplusone [Pseudo-code](https://tio.run/##dVFBasMwELzrFQOBYjVpbKcUSkgLTg499mB6MmoxRLE3cSQji6Z9vbuKTQMp3YOklWZmd7Ttt6@tue/p2Frn4UqztUeR4QnFcJ6HjYyPkhkeEomddSCQCdBKR@niUSrRuoDIZO8TZvqUl6xIlLgGz9Bowzi5FOCgHaKsoLtUYcUEUuN9iLPS8Hi5G4RJXbOf/2P/5Qa9PNhTgnhLxammRnOXq7G3QeQMIYUp8qEY54RbLMQ6vBRBW00LVuU2CDfYQzedDoWD6X0wnavr3xrdK7FhkY4/XG@jtcQEb0ytvW@7ZRxrMz/RgVq9pXJuXRWHLM4ZTab6MNqfrDv8@hpighf61Aa@Lj1eI4PGVjDyXINZGFnQX9T52R@yr6lD2VTWka@P4GTUeF@wyjjegnikF0cbJfv@Bw)

Comment: `<wx gtw gwx gxt <xy gty gyx gxt <wx gxw gwt <yz gtz gzy gyt <xy gyx gxt <wx gxw gwt` shows more clearly what's going on, and also uses one fewer temporary to boot. The three-register sort is also now only 11 instructions: `<xy gty gyx gxt <yz gtz gzy gyt <xy gyx gxt`.

Answer (score 1):

### <s>23</s> 22 instructions

Here's a different approach from l4m2's bubble sort — we can use insertion sort. We start by sorting *x, y, z*. Then we insert *w* in its proper place by starting at the top and working downward: If *w > z*, insert it and bump out the old *z* into *q*. If *w > y*, insert *q* and bump out the old *y* into *q*. And so on.
An "unoptimized" sequence of instructions that works for that second part is:

```
mpw mtx muy mvz
<vp mqp lqv lvp
mau <up luq lqa
<tp lpt ltq
mwp mxt myu mzv
```

I can optimize that and append it to <s>l4m2's 12</s> Neil's 11-instruction `sort3` to produce this <s>23</s> 22-instruction `sort4`:

```
<zy lty lyz lzt
<yx ltx lxy lyt
<zy lyz lzt
mqw <zw lqz lzw
<yw lty lyq lqt
<xw lwx lxq
```

But I don't see how to shrink it further than that.

And it still uses 6 `<` instructions. Is it conceivably possible to use only 5? Here's a 20-instruction `sort4` (based on [this sorting network](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SimpleSortingNetwork2.svg)) that uses only 5 comparisons but is *not stable*, so it doesn't fulfill the challenge:

```
<wy gtw gwy gyt
<xz gtx gxz gzt
<wx gtw gwx gxt
<yz gty gyz gzt
<xy gtx gxy gyt
```

I'm also (finally) realizing that I should have given not only `cmovl` and `cmovg` but also `cmovle` and `cmovge` as primitives; I wonder if that would have helped at all.

Comment: Since `sort3` is now down to 11 instructions, this can be reduced to 22: `<xy gty gyx gxt <yz gtz gzy gyt <xy gyx gxt mqw <zw lqz lzw <yw lty lyq lqt <xw lwx lxq`.

Comment: Oh, you have a tweaked `sort3`... I'm sure you can figure out what I meant...

Answer (score 0):

### 32 instructions

Here's yet another approach: mergesort. This successfully minimizes the number of `<` operations to 5, but we pay for it with a lot more cmovs. We start by sorting the sublists {*w*, *x*} and {*y*, *z*}; then we merge those two lists. But "merge the two lists" is harder than it sounds. I wrote out the complete game tree; e.g. "First compare *w* ≤ *y*. If true, the next step will be to compare *x* ≤ *y*; otherwise, the next step will be to compare *w* ≤ *z*" and so on. Then rewrite as "If *w* ≤ *y*, set *i,j* ← *x,y*; otherwise, set *i,j* ← *w,z*. The next step is to compare *i* ≤ *j*" and so on. That gives an unoptimized program [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/e48v1h55e):

```
<wx gtw gwx gxt
<yz gty gyz gzt
maw mbx mcy mdz
<ac
  mwa mib mjc m1c m2d m3c m4d m5b m6d m7d m8b
  gwc gia gjd g1b g2d g3d g4b g5a g6b g7a g8b
<ij
  mxi
  gxj g15 g26 g37 g48
<bd
  my1 mz2
  gy3 gz4
```

My best-optimized version takes 32 instructions:

```
<wx gtw gwx gxt
<yz gty gyz gzt
m3y m4z m5x m6z m7z m8x
<wy g48 g5w g6x g7w gwy gx5 gy8 g3z
<x3 gx3 gy5 gz6 g37 g48
<8z gy3 gz4
```